Beamer "allowframebreaks" option but only with frametitle on the first slide
I would like to have the frametitle "References" only on the first slide and no frametitle on the following slides of the broken frame. Is this possible to achieve?
\documentclass[11pt, aspectratio=1610, xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    
    \section*{References}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        
        \bibliography{references.bib}
        
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

As suggested here, put the following in the preamble of your .tex file:
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}}
\makeatother

